# Fourier transform of the Heisenberg antiferromagnetic model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, fourier-transform, bosons

I have a short question about the Fourier transform of the antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model.

The Hamiltonian, written in terms of bosonic operators, is:
$$ \widehat{H} = -NJ\hbar^2s^2 + J\hbar^2s \sum_{i}\left[\widehat{a}_{i}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{i} + \widehat{a}_{i + 1}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{i + 1} + \widehat{a}_{i}\widehat{a}_{i + 1} + \widehat{a}_{i}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{i + 1}^{\dagger}  \right] $$.

The question is, use the Fourier transform and show that:
$$ \widehat{H} = -NJ\hbar^2s^2 + J\hbar^2s \sum_{k}\left[2\widehat{a}_{k}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{k} + \cos\left(ka\right)\left(\widehat{a}_{k}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{-k}^{\dagger} + \widehat{a}_{k}\widehat{a}_{-k} \right)  \right] $$.

The Fourier transform:
$$\widehat{a}_{j} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}\sum_{k}e^{-ikja}\widehat{a}_{k} 
$$
$$  \widehat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}\sum_{k}e^{ikja}\widehat{a}_{k}^{\dagger} $$

I derived that:
$$ \widehat{H} = -NJ\hbar^2s^2 + J\hbar^2s \sum_{k}\left[2\widehat{a}_{k}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{k} + e^{ika}\widehat{a}_{k}\widehat{a}_{-k} + e^{-ika}\widehat{a}_{k}^{\dagger}\widehat{a}_{-k}^{\dagger}  \right] $$.

My question is, where does that cosine come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to well known identity, You have
$$
\sum_ke^{ika}\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} = \sum_k \cos(ka)\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} + i\sum_k \sin(ka)\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k}
$$
Since the sum contains $-k$ for each $k$ and due to commutativity $\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} = \hat{a}_{-k}\hat{ a }_{k}$, sum with sine is zero:
$$
\sum_k \sin(ka)\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} = \sum_{-k} \sin(ka)\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} = [k\rightarrow -k] = \sum_{k} \sin(-ka)\hat{a}_{-k}\hat{a}_{k} =
$$
$$
= - \sum_{k} \sin(ka)\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_{-k} = 0
$$